# Is $y=-2x+2.5$ a singular solution to the differential equation $y'=(4x+2y-1)^{1/2}?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

I have a hunch that $y=-2x+2.5$ is a singular solution to the differential equation $$y'=(4x+2y-1)^\frac{1}{2}$$But I don't know if I'm right. Furthermore, I don't know how to check if I'm right. How do I proceed?

Comment: Compute $y'$, plug $y$ and $y'$ into your DE, and see what you get.

Comment: I did that, and I get -2=sqrt(4). But how do I know if it's singular?

Comment: @Eckhard I thought OP concerns the uniqueness by asking this question, not just checking if LHS equals RHS.

Comment: @Shuhao Cao Right

Comment: @AbhishekMallela: Were you given an initial condition?

Comment: The Maple code $$ode := diff(y(x), x) = (4*x+2*y(x)-1)^{1/2}:with(DEtools): odetest(y(x) = -2*x+2.5, ode) $$ produces $-4.00000000$ so that function is not any solution of the ODE under consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all set $t=4x+2y-1$ and then try to write the OE with respect to this new substitution to find the following ODE: $$\frac{dt}{dx}=2\sqrt{2}+4$$.
- Solve the later OE.
- Assuming the function $y=-2x+2.5$ is the solution of the original OE, check if this function *can be achieved* from the one-parameter family of solutions of the original OE.

If $y$ cannot be achieved by putting some $C_1$ in the family of solutions, then it is a singular solution.

Comment: Lovely answer +1